# SwiftUI. Preview with CoreData – populating, singleton and weird behaviour

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, preview

I have a small app which can add and save arbitrary Events to CoreData.
And I'm struggling with preparing of preview data.

**Correct behaviour**

**In preview window I see one text with content "Test event"**

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
       
        //init coredata
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        container.loadPersistentStores() { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Can't load core data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        //adding event
        let event = Event(context: container.viewContext)
        event.id = UUID()
        event.name = "Test"
        try! container.viewContext.save()
        
        //getting events
        let request = Event.fetchRequest()
        let events = try! container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        
        //view
        return VStack {
            ForEach(events, id: \.id) { event in
                Text("\(event.id?.uuidString ?? "") \(event.name ?? "") fs")
            }
        }
}
```

**But if I try to move logic to DataController, I get 7 Text blocks with the same name, but different UUIDs**

```
class DataController {
    
    static let preview = DataController()
    
    private(set) var container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    private init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        
        self.container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")       
        
        
        container.loadPersistentStores() { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Can't load core data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }    
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static let dataController = DataController.preview
    
    static var previews: some View {

        //adding event
        let event = Event(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
        event.id = UUID()
        event.name = "Test event"
        try! dataController.container.viewContext.save()
        
        //getting events
        let request = Event.fetchRequest()
        let events = try! dataController.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        
        //view
        return VStack {
            ForEach(events, id: \.id) { event in
                Text("\(event.id?.uuidString ?? "") \(event.name ?? "")")
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**What can cause such behaviour?**

Model for Event was manually generated. The only thing I changed – commenting @objc(Event), because with this statement preview doesn't work at all.

Comment: You are initializing your DataController for preview with inMemory set to false, it should be set to true.

Comment: Joakim, thanks for answer.

But if I understand correctly, for inMemory storage I have to add just this line
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null").

And this line exists. There is a slight mistake in init, I forgot to remove param inMemory – it doesn't participate in initialisation in reality .

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it wasn’t used.